# A referral form asks me to list 3 negative aspects of this coworker's work. Will it hurt this persons chances if I don't?

Tags: recommendation-letter

I am a referral for a former coworker. The referral form, which is hosted online, asks me to list "the top 3 ways that this individual could improve upon their work performance."

I think this person would be a great asset to the research team, I am happy to write them a referral, and I don't feel comfortable trying to squeeze out 3 negative aspects of this person's work. Will it hurt their opportunity if I don't adhere to what is being asked of me? One thought I had was to perhaps list one or two and move on to the next field.

Comment: What is the connection to academia here?

Comment: Your title and body say to separate things. The title is about *negative* aspects, the body is about *improving* aspects. Surely there are some things they can improve to become even better?

Comment: This may be more on topic at Workplace.SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is impossible to correctly second-guess the intentions of the person sending you the form. One possibility is that the question is deliberately provocative and that if you list anything negative at all, the person will be excluded from consideration. A second possibility is that you're expected to list something which, at first sight, might appear to be negative but that the person being recommended could turn into a positive at an interview. Thirdly, it might be assumed that any genuine and thoughtful referee must have something negative to say about another person.

In your situation, I tend to fill the unwanted space with "see below" or "see further comments" (even if I have to write those comments, literally, outside the box) and then simply stress that the person's attributes are such that I am delighted to recommend them without reservation.

It might not be what is expected but it's honest, and the best I can do.